# How many watches ng-switch creates?

Tags: angularjs

Simple: **How many watches does ng-switch place?**

For example:

```
    <section ng-switch="value">
        <div ng-switch-when="1">1</div>
        <div ng-switch-when="2">2</div>
        <div ng-switch-when="3">3</div>
        <div ng-switch-when="4">4</div>
    </section>
```

Will that create one watch? four?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ngSwitch` creates a single watcher on the expression in `ng-switch` attribute.

One easy way to check is to do the following in the controller:

```
// $timeout is a crude way to "wait" until ng-switch sets up the watcher
$timeout(function(){
  console.log($scope.$$watchers ? $scope.$$watchers.length : 0);
})
```

Another, is to do this (minus 1 is because this expression introduces its own $watch):

```
<pre>{{$$watchers.length - 1}}</pre>
<section ng-switch="value">
  <div ng-switch-when="1">...</div>
  ...
</section>
```

And yet another, is by going to the [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.0-rc.1/src/ng/directive/ngSwitch.js) and seeing a single `$scope.$watch` there :) - and, of course, the fact that there are no isolate scope bindings

Comment: FWIW, [angular-stats](https://github.com/kentcdodds/ng-stats) is a great tool for monitoring watches in (mostly) real time.